# Edge Transport Server missing from Hybrid Configuration Wizard

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

After initially running the Hybrid Configuration Wizard (but not migrating any mailboxes) we've since added an Edge Transport Server to our Exchange 2010 SP3 RU13 environment. The intention being to route O365 mail through the newly build Edge Transport Server I fired up the HCW to discover that the Edge server isn't available to select.

Am I missing something? The Edge Transport server has an Edge subscription with our internal Hub transport server.

[image]

I was expecting the wizard to give me something like https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/31/06/metablogapi/5468.image_thumb_7DC9B6CA.png

As I'm not getting an error message I'm having a hard time googling for any logical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps someone else. It turns out that at the time of this post the Hybrid Configuration Wizard doesn't support configuration of Exchange 2010 Edge servers. As per https://portal.office.com/onboarding/finishhybridex2010#/

[image]

I've found some instructions to perform these steps manually under the heading **Sidebar: Hybrid Deployment when using Edge Transport** on this link -
http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/office-365/exchange-online/configuring-exchange-hybrid-deployment-migrating-to-office-365-exchange-online-part11.html

> Since the Hybrid Configuration Wizard (HCW) hasn't been developed with Edge Transport servers in mind, there are several post steps you need to go through after you have configured a standard hybrid deployment.
>
> 1. Deploy the Exchange 2010 Edge Transport servers
>    Obviously, one of the first post steps is to deploy the Exchange 2010 Edge Transport servers in the perimeter network.
> 2. Configure EdgeSync After having deployed the Exchange 2010 Edge Transport servers, you must subscribe them to the respective Active Directory site that holds the Exchange hybrid servers using Edge Synchronization.
> 3. Configure an Edge Transport DNS record You must create a CNAME or A-record (such as edge.fabrikam.com) in external DNS that points to the Edge Transport servers public IP address.
> 4. Update SPF You should also remember to update your SPF record to include the new Exchange 2010 Edge Transport servers.
> 5. Import the hybrid configuration certificate on the Edge Transport servers You need to export the certificate used for the hybrid configuration from one of the hybrid servers and import it on the Edge Transport servers. When imported, you must assign it to SMTP (without overwriting the default self-signed certificate).
> 6. Re-run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard You need to re-run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard and make sure the public IP address is associated with the Exchange 2010 Edge Transport servers and specify the FQDN for the Edge Transport servers (i.e. edge.fabrikam.com).
> 7. Modify the Office 365 Outbound Connector You need to modify the send connector created by the Hybrid Configuration Wizard (HCW) and, more specifically, change the source servers from the hybrid servers to the Edge Transport servers.
> 8. Configure the default Receive Connector on the Edge Transport servers Finally, you need to configure the default Receive Connector on each Exchange 2010 Edge Transport server. More specifically, you need to enable support for the XOORG protocol.